# Apps Script Function to Erase Cell Containing Certain Text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I’m working on a Google Sheet for work (not allowed to share), and I want to create an Apps Script Function that parses through all the data and erases cell content if they contain “?”, “PPS”, “LES”, “MPES”,or “PSPEC”. I can’t find any way to do it without deleting the whole row, which i don’t want. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function delIfContains() {
  const contains = ["?","PPSF","LES","MPES","PSPEC"];//needles
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();//haystack
  contain.forEach(s => {
    sh.createTextFinder(s).matchEntireCell(false).findAll().forEach(rg => rg.clearContent());//reaper
  });
}
```

[textFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Thank you that’s really helpful! However I’m getting an “Out of Memory Error”, do you maybe know why? Thanks again.

Comment: I haven't had an out of memory error  for a long time.  I used to get them when I designed websites and it was normally a php issue but I have not heard of one associated with Google Apps Script but perhaps if you asked it as a question that sounds like something TheMaster or Tanaike might know something about

Answer (score 0):

Cooper already showed how to do this with a loop that creates a [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) for value separately. To match all values in one go, use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), like this:

```js
function test() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  const regexString = '\\?|PPS|LES|MPES|PSPEC';
  const numCleared = clearMatchingCells_(range, regexString);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(`Cleared ${numCleared} cell(s).`);
}

/**
* Clears cells in a range that match a regular expression.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} range The range to search.
* @param {String} regexString The pattern to match with cells in range.
*/
function clearMatchingCells_(range, regexString) {
  const matches = range
    .createTextFinder(regexString)
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .findAll();
  matches.forEach(cell => cell.clearContent());
  return matches.length;
}
```

Note that any regex special characters such as `?` and `*` need to be [double escaped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping) in `regexString`.

Answer (score 0):

As another approach, how about using `replaceAllWith` with TextFinder as follows?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const search = ["\\?", "PPS", "LES", "MPES", "PSPEC"];
  const r = search.map(e => `.*${e}.*`).join("|");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().createTextFinder(r).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith("");
}
```

- When this script is run, the cell values including `search` are replaced with `""`.

#### Reference:

- [replaceAllWith(replaceText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceallwithreplacetext)